# Find the asymptotes

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Find the asymptotes of $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},f(x)=\sqrt[3]{e^{x}-e^{2x}+e^{4x}\ln^{2}(1+e^{-x})}. $

I found that $y=0$ is an asymptote when $ x\rightarrow -\infty $, but how do I calculate $ \lim_{x\to\infty }f(x) $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let see what happens when $x\to \infty$. We have $\ln(1+y)= y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O(y^4)$ as $y\to 0$ hence
$$
f(x)= \left(e^x-e^{2x}+e^{4x}\left(e^{-x}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}+\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}+O(e^{-4x})\right)^2\right)^{1/3}
$$
that is
$$
f(x)= \left(e^x-e^{2x}+e^{4x}\left(e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}+\frac{11}{12}e^{-4x}+O(e^{-5x})\right)\right)^{1/3}
$$
therefore
$$
f(x)= \left(\frac{11}{12}+O(e^{-x})\right)^{1/3}.
$$

In particular, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)^{1/3}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by $ O(y^{4}) $?

Comment: @ztefelina Given functions $f,g: \mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$, we write $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to \infty$ as a shorthand for $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$, for some $C>0$ and all sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I cannot understand how you obtained that $ \left ( e^{-x}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}+\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}+O(e^{-4x}) \right )^{2}=e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}+\frac{11}{12}e^{-4x}+O(e^{-5x}) $.

Comment: @ztefelina What do you do if you have to compute manually $(a+b+c+d)^2$? Try it from the biggest to lowest terms :)

Comment: But is it true that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty }e^{4x}ln^{2}(1+e^{-x})=0 $, as I stated before?

Comment: Yes it s correct ;)